# Converting a two's complement in fix-point arithmetic (with bit numbering) to decimal number

Tags: binary, numbers, decimal, converters, number-formatting

I'm wondering how you could convert a two's complement in fix-point arithmetic to a decimal number.

So let's say we got this fix-point arithmetic in two's complement: `11001011` with bit numbering, with `2` positions behind the decimal point, and want form it to a decimal number.

We already know that the decimal will be negative because the first bit is a `1`.

`2` positions behind decimal point, so we have `110010 11`.

Convert that from two's complement to normal form (`sub` by `1`, `invert`):

`110010 10` (i sub by `1` here)

`001101 01` (i inverted here)

`001101` in decimal is `13`

`01` in decimal is `1`

So in the end we get to `-13.1`. Is that correct or there isn't even a way to convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is just to convert the whole value to an integer (ignoring the fixed point, initially), then scale the result.

So for your example where you have a 6.2 fixed point number: `110010 10`:

Convert as integer:

```
11001010 = -54
```

Divide by scale factor = 2^2:

```
-54 / 4 = -13.5
```

Note that the fractional part is always unsigned. (You can probably see now that `10` would give you `+ 0.5` for the fractional part, i.e. `00` = `0.0`, `01` = `+0.25`, `10 = +0.5`, `11 = +0.75`.)

Comment: Oh wow thanks for answer and sharing this method with me, didn't know it will work like that as well! :)

Comment: @cnmesr: you're welcome - you will probably find that it helps to just think of fixed point numbers as *integers with an implicit scaling factor*.

Answer (score 0):

A small note (but very important in understanding your question) - when you say "decimal point", do you really mean decimal? or do you mean "binary" point.
Meaning, if it's a decimal point, you can position it after you convert to decimal, to see how many **decimal** digits should remain to the right of the point, but if you mean binary point, it means in the binary representation how many bits represent the fraction part.
In your example, it seems that you meant binary point, and then the integer part is 001101(bin) = 13(dec) and the fraction part is 0.01(bin)=0.25(dec), because the first bit to the right of the point represents 1/2, the second represents 1/4 and so on, and the whole thing is then negated.
**Total result then will be -13.25**